# Update img after ginput in matlab GUI

Tags: image, matlab, button, user-interface, refresh

I'm doing a little interface on matlab right now and I have a problem. 
So basically, I have an image and two buttons, the first one is to rotate the image (taking 2 coordinates with `ginput(2)`) and the second is to crop the image (taking two coordinates too).

I'd like to update my image when I have the 2 x and the 2 y.

So, I declare my image here :

```
function projetGUI_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)

% Choose default command line output for projetGUI
handles.output = hObject;

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);
axes(handles.axes1);
img = imread('plaque3.png');
imshow(img)
```

This is my first button :

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

[x,y] =ginput(2);

angleRad = atan((y(2)-y(1))/(x(2)-x(1)));
angleDeg = radtodeg(angleRad);

img = imrotate(img, angleDeg);
imshow(img);
set (handles.text1, 'String' ,'Résults ') ;
```

this is my second button :

```
function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

[xcrop,ycrop] = ginput(2);

largeur = xcrop(2) - xcrop(1);
hauteur = ycrop(2) - ycrop(1);

img = imcrop(img,[xcrop(1) ycrop(1) largeur hauteur]);
imshow(img);
set (handles.text1, 'String' ,'Results ') ;
```

And this is the error I got :

```
Undefined function or variable "img".

Error in projetGUI>pushbutton1_Callback (line 91)
img = imrotate(img, angleDeg);

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 96)
        feval(varargin{:});

Error in projetGUI (line 43)
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in
@(hObject,eventdata)projetGUI('pushbutton1_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))


Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
```

I'm pretty sure that the problem appears because my image isn't a global variable but I didn't find the right way to declare it.

Anyone could help me ?

Many thanks =)
(by the way, sorry for my english, it's not my mother tongue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are `pushbutton1_Callback` and `pushbutton2_Callback` nested functions of `projetGUI_OpeningFcn`? If not, then yes, `img` only exists in the workspace of `projetGUI_OpeningFcn`, but not in the other two functions' workspaces.

A possible workaround is to use `handles.img` instead of `img` in your `projetGUI_OpeningFcn` and `guidata(hObject, handles);` ***at the end*** of each function. The image will then be accessible by the other functions as `handles.img`.

See the [documentation on `guidata`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html) for more info.